# can't find module useGard Microservice

Tags: nestjs

Hi I've finish monolithique web api and I'm trying to upgrade it to a microservice one.
I'm following the few little information I can find on how to do it with nestJs but I'm having a problem. I think it's a simple and stupid problem but I can't figure it out.

```
DeprecationWarning: 'getMutableClone' has been deprecated since v4.0.0. Use an appropriate `factory.update...` method instead, use `setCommentRange` or `setSourceMapRange`, and avoid setting `parent`.
Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core/guards'
Require stack:
- D:\programs\serveur\product-server\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\microservices-module.js
- D:\programs\serveur\product-server\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\nest-microservice.js
- D:\programs\serveur\product-server\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\index.js
- D:\programs\serveur\product-server\dist\main.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\programs\serveur\product-server\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\microservices-module.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
```

it can't find the useGuard Module but it should be added with the @nestjs/core that I've correctly added with the latest version.

```js
import { INestMicroservice } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Create the microservice options object
const microserviceOptions = {
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    host: process.env.HOST, //
    port: process.env.PORT,
  },
};

(async () => {
  const app: INestMicroservice = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(
    AppModule,
    microserviceOptions,
  );

  await app.listen();

  console.info('Microservice is listening...', process.env.PORT || 8080);
})();
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env' })],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `nest info`?